# I want to make sure that if the user answers the question correctly, then points are added to him, and the total number of points is saved in the db

Tags: django

I want to make sure that if the user answers the question correctly, then points are added to him, and the total number of points is saved in the db, but the problem is that the wrong type is constantly or something else is wrong

It's a model, but it's probably not needed.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title_task = models.CharField(verbose_name="Заголовок", max_length=128)
    description_task = models.TextField(verbose_name="Задание")
    created_at_task = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at_task = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, verbose_name="Пользователь", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_task = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Обложка", upload_to="advertisements/", blank=True, null=True)
    right_answer = models.CharField(verbose_name="Верный ответ",default=1, max_length=128)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tasks'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"task(id = {self.id}, title = {self.title_task})"
    
    @admin.display(description="дата создания")
    def created_date_task(self):
 
        if self.created_at_task.date() == timezone.now().date():
            created_time_task = self.created_at_task.time().strftime("%H:%M")
            return format_html("<span style = 'color:blue;'>Сегодня в {} </span>",created_time_task)
        else:
            return self.created_at_task.strftime("%d:%m%y в %H:%M")

    @admin.display(description="дата обновления")
    def update_date_task(self):
    
        if self.update_at_task.date() == timezone.now().date():
            update_time_task = self.update_at_task.time().strftime("%H:%M")
            return format_html("<span style = 'color:blue;'>Сегодня в {} </span>", update_time_task)
        else:
            return self.update_at_task.strftime("%d:%m%y в %H:%M")

    @admin.display(description="Изображение")
    def image_mini_task(self):
        if self.image_task:
            return format_html("<img src='{}' style = 'width:40px;'>", self.image_task.url)
        
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('task', kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

another model, but it is already available to users

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Баллы", default=0)
```

viev.py

```
@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy("login"))
def task(request, pk):
    answer = request.POST.get("answer")
    points = int(Profile.objects.values_list("points", flat=True).get(pk = ))
    tasks = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    if answer:
        if answer == tasks.right_answer: 
            text = "верно"
            points += 1
        else:
            text = "неверно"
    else:
        text = ""
    context = {"tasks": tasks, "text" : text}
    return render(request, "app_advertisement/task.html", context=context)
```

I've tried a lot on the Internet but there's nothing like it on the Internet

Answer (score 0):

You can change it like this, it looks like you're getting the points of a user and adding 1 to that. But you're not actually assigning those points to the user.

```
@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy("login"))
def task(request, pk):
    answer = request.POST.get("answer")
    points = int(Profile.objects.values_list("points", flat=True).get(pk = ))
    tasks = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    if answer:
        if answer == tasks.right_answer: 
            text = "верно"
            profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk) # alternatively you could also do request.user.profile
            profile.points += 1
            profile.save()
        else:
            text = "неверно"
    else:
        text = ""
    context = {"tasks": tasks, "text" : text}
    return render(request, "app_advertisement/task.html", context=context)
```

The method above works, but even cleaner would be like this:

```
from django.db.models import F

profile.points = F("points") + 1
```

This makes sure that the addition of a point is done in the database, instead of in python. As this is only for a single user it doesn't matter but it points could be added simultaneously they might interfere with each other.

Comment: DoesnNotExist (Несуществующее) в /task/4
Profile matching query does not exist.        this caused such an exception